# Extract Jotform Product Data from Multi Line Cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, jotform

I am using Jotform for customers to place quarterly orders, and we then receive this data into a google sheet. Unfortunately Jotform's product list places all the items into one multi-line cell, so when trying to total the number of cases for each item to know how much to order from our suppliers it is difficult to extract the information.

As an example the data we receive would be something like:

```
Product 1 (Amount: 32.00 USD, Number of cases: 66)
Product 2 (Amount: 16.00 USD, Number of cases: 2)
Product 5 (Amount: 35.00 USD, Number of cases: 3)
Product 6 (Amount: 17.00 USD, Number of cases: 3)
Product 9 (Amount: 13.00 USD, Number of cases: 1)
Product 10 (Amount: 12.00 USD, Number of cases: 4)
Total: 2,361.00 USD
```

There are 26 products in total, and while they do seem to come in the same order, not all products are present in each order.

I have tried several things with regex, splitting lines by CHAR(10), but can't quite find a simple solution to it. What I would like is an output where I could perhaps create a set of columns for each product and have the number of cases for that product on each row for our customer.

A sample with a small variety of the order lines is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ygxtKLeMGtivGKbYRRH89X7AzDThRll7PpEWhot7ldU/edit?usp=sharing)

One solution that has proved promising is using the function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70258670/google-sheets-split-multi-line-cell-into-new-rows-duplicate-surrounding-row-e) solution combined with a regex/substitute hybrid, this can be seen on the 'expand_split' tab in the linked sheetand following table:

| Customer | Order | Product 1 | Product 2 | Product 3 | Product 4 | Product 5 | Product 6 | Product 7 | Product 8 | Product 9 | Product 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer 1 | Product 1 (Amount: 32.00 USD, Number of cases: 30) | 30 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 1 | Product 2 (Amount: 16.00 USD, Number of cases: 28) | 0 | 28 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 1 | Product 3 (Amount: 19.00 USD, Number of cases: 17) | 0 | 0 | 17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 1 | Product 5 (Amount: 9.00 USD, Number of cases: 25) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 1 | Product 7 (Amount: 35.00 USD, Number of cases: 35) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 35 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 1 | Product 9 (Amount: 17.00 USD, Number of cases: 33) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 33 | 0 |
| Customer 1 | Product 10 (Amount: 13.00 USD, Number of cases: 17) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 17 |
| Customer 1 | Total: 8,613.00 USD | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 2 | Product 1 (Amount: 32.00 USD, Number of cases: 10) | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 2 | Product 2 (Amount: 16.00 USD, Number of cases: 8) | 0 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 2 | Product 3 (Amount: 19.00 USD, Number of cases: 8) | 0 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 2 | Product 5 (Amount: 9.00 USD, Number of cases: 8) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 2 | Product 7 (Amount: 35.00 USD, Number of cases: 12) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 2 | Product 8 (Amount: 12.00 USD, Number of cases: 20) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 2 | Product 9 (Amount: 17.00 USD, Number of cases: 16) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 16 | 0 |
| Customer 2 | Product 10 (Amount: 13.00 USD, Number of cases: 8) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 |
| Customer 2 | Total: 8,156.00 USD | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 3 | Product 1 (Amount: 32.00 USD, Number of cases: 3) | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 3 | Product 2 (Amount: 16.00 USD, Number of cases: 3) | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 3 | Product 3 (Amount: 19.00 USD, Number of cases: 3) | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 3 | Product 7 (Amount: 35.00 USD, Number of cases: 3) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 3 | Product 8 (Amount: 12.00 USD, Number of cases: 4) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| Customer 3 | Product 9 (Amount: 17.00 USD, Number of cases: 3) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Customer 3 | Product 10 (Amount: 13.00 USD, Number of cases: 3) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| Customer 3 | Total: 1,179.00 USD |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

with the following code pulling the data from the product line in B2:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH($B2, C$1), 
SUBSTITUTE(MID($B2,SEARCH("Number of cases: ",$B2,1)+17,3),")",""), 
0)
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: some more details, links, tables etc added to hopefully make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this if every product in a **each row**.

```
=ArrayFormula({
      {"Products";"Amount";"Number of cases"},
        SPLIT(BYROW({"(.+)\(";"\(Amount: (.*) USD,";"Number of cases: (.*)\)"},
              LAMBDA(re, TEXTJOIN("|",1,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A6, ""&re&""))))),"|")})
```

[image]

Or this formula if all the input is in a **single cell**

```
=ArrayFormula({
      {"Products";"Amount";"Number of cases"},
        SPLIT(BYROW({"(.+)\(";"\(Amount: (.*) USD,";"Number of cases: (.*)\)"},
              LAMBDA(re, TEXTJOIN("|",1,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, CHAR(10))), ""&re&""))))),"|")})
```

[image]

### Update

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(rg, QUERY(TRANSPOSE({{"Products";"Amount";"Number of cases"},
        SPLIT(BYROW({"(.+)\(";"\(Amount: (.*) USD,";"Number of cases: (.*)\)"},
              LAMBDA(re, TEXTJOIN("|",1,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(rg, CHAR(10))))," where not Col1 contains 'Total:'  "), ""&re&""))))),"|")}), 
                    "Select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3) group by Col1 order by sum(Col2) desc ",1))(B2:B))
```

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`SPLIT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) - [**`BYROW`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`TEXTJOIN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992) - [**`IFERROR`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) - [**`REGEXEXTRACT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) - [**`TRANSPOSE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262) - [**`CHAR`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120) - [**`QUERY`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) - [**`FLATTEN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) - [**`NOT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093305) - [**`SUM`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)

Comment: This seems almost what I'm after, the main issue I have is that I have multiple rows of orders on the sheet and what I really want is to be able to pull the total for each product all on one line to make it easier to collate

Comment: @rory the answer is updated take a look